# VUE nested route gives the empty page

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

My routine returns an empty page for the children's route. Checked on the web, but can't find anything useful. I have the following setup.

Vue routes in the same index.js file

```
    {
        path: "/admin",
        name: "Admin",
        component: Admin,
        
        children:[
            
          {
            path: "/scheduler",
            name: "Scheduler",
            component: Scheduler,
            meta: {
              role: "user",
              middleware: [auth],
              requiresAuth: true,
            },
          },
          
        ],
        meta: {
          role: "user",
          middleware: [auth],
          requiresAuth: true,
        },
      },
```

my beforeEach :

```js
    router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
      if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
        if (window.localStorage.getItem("token") == null) {
          next({
            path: "/login",
            query: {
              redirect: to.fullPath,
            },
          });
        } else {
          const localData = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("user")).role;
    
          const middleware = to.meta.middleware;
          
          const context = { to, from, next };
    
          //If there is no error from Auth, Unauthorized 
    
          if (store.getters.errorDetails == null) {
            middleware[0]({ ...context }).then(() => {
              if (localData == "user" && to.meta.role == "user") {
                if (to.meta.role == "admin") {
                  next("/user");
                }
                next("/user");
              } else if (localData == "admin" && to.meta.role == "admin") {
                if (to.meta.role == "user") {
                  next("/admin");
                } else {
                  next("/admin");
                }
              } else {
                next("/login");
              }
            });
          }
        }
      } else {
        next();
      }
    });
```

and I can see the following screen. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JW1Rs.png)

Comment: What's scheduler component content hav

Comment: I have the Vuetify calendar component, it is a big component itself, I didn't want to add it here, but there is content in the component.